# Test case using powerMock in java for class new object mock

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermock

I am trying to mock the class instance of a user which is created inside another class which is `MyClass` method count.

I want to write unit test case for `Myclass` method `count`

Below is sample code

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
class User{
    public int count(){
        return 123;
    }
}

class MyClass{
    public int count(){
        User user = new User();
        return user.count();
    }
}


@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest( MyClass.class)
public class ServiceTestClass{
  
    @Test
    public void testMethod() throws Exception {


        User user = Mockito.mock(User.class);
        when(user.count()).thenReturn(45);
        whenNew(User.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(user);
        MyClass myClass= new MyClass();
        System.out.println(myClass.count());
        verifyNew(User.class).withNoArguments();

    }

}
```

Idealy, `System.out.println(myClass.count());` should print `45` but it's printing `123`.

Can anyone please help what i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Powermock has no support for junit 5. If you do the same with junit 4 it should work.

Comment: I am using 'junit:junit:4.13.1'

Comment: are you sure?  the import statement org.junit.jupiter.api.Test says its junit 5

Comment: I have added in gralde the same version mention above

Comment: ok then you need to **use org.junit.Test** to run tests and make sure you also have org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.9.2 on the classpath